# React Native including component inside a ScrollView not working

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-component

I'm building and app where I'm trying to include a component named Header.js inside navigation forlder. I'm working with functional components throughout the app. Also the images are not working. I'm new with React Native.

Here's the error

```
Unable to resolve module `./src/navigation/Header` from `src/screens/userprofile/Profilecard.js`:
```

None of these files exist:

- src/screens/userprofile/src/navigation/Header(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- src/screens/userprofile/src/navigation/Header/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)

RCTFatal
__28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
**CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
start

I dont't understand what am I doing wrong I check multiple videos on youtube including (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hf4MJH0jDb4 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEa48P-KtCw)

This my Profile.js where I'm including Header

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
View, 
Text, 
StyleSheet, 
Image, 
TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Header } from './src/navigation/Header';


const ProfileCard = () => {

return(
    <ScrollView>
        <View  style={styles.container}>

            <Header/>

            <View style={styles.profileCard}>
                <Text style={styles.cardHeading}>
                    Faithful
                </Text>
                <Image style={styles.cardImg} source={'./assets/img/logo.png'}/>
                <Text style={styles.cardText}>
                    The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate.
                </Text>
                <View style={styles.cardOptions}>
                    <Image style={styles.iconImg} source={'./assets/img/icons/download.png'}/>
                    <Image style={styles.iconImg} source={'./assets/img/icons/heart.png'}/>
                    <Image style={styles.iconImg} source={'./assets/img/icons/share.png'}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
);
```

}

This is Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
View, 
Text, 
StyleSheet, 
Image, 
TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

const Header = () => {
return(
    <View style={styles.header}>

        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image style={styles.logoImg} source={'./assets/img/logo.png'}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image style={styles.profileIcon} source={'./assets/img/icons/avatar.png'}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image style={styles.settingsIcon} source={'./assets/img/icons/settings.png'}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        
    </View>
);
}
export default Header();

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    }
});
```

Folders:

```
src/screens
src/navigation
src/assetes/img
src/assets/fonts
src/other
```

Comment: Can you share Header codes ?

Comment: @OAslan I added header code in the end.

Comment: Try to change `export default Header()` to `export default Header`

Comment: That did not worked.

Comment: import Header from './src/navigation/Header'; when you are making default export you don’t need to specify curly braces

Comment: @akshaylalwani I have tried that too.

Comment: You are importing scrollview from gesture handler import it from react native and don’t forget to remove curly braces

Comment: @akshaylalwani That did not work.

Comment: Can you share project structure ? Where are Header.js and Profile.js ?

Comment: @OAslan I added folder names at the end.

Comment: Profile.js in which folder?

Comment: @OAslan Profile.js is in src/screns/userprofile/Profilecard.js. I missspelled Profilecard.js with profile.js

Comment: Can you try this; `import  Header  from '../navigation/Header';`

Comment: @OAslan That did not work. I was able to solve the image problem though.

Comment: Sorry my mistake that should be `import  Header  from '../../navigation/Header';`

Comment: @OAslan I was able to resolve it by changing my functional component to class component and I used the same path you mentioned. Now I have another issue where the app cannot find the images I am using react-native-asset package. Sometime they show-up sometime don't. It's annoying.

Comment: Why do you use react-native-asset ? For ease to path ?

Comment: @OAslan No just to automate the asset linking and unlinking.

Comment: Did you try rebuild your project or can you share asset config ?